# styling a bootstrap dropdown menu

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm not sure why my CSS is not hitting my HTML and styling it correctly.

HTML:

```
<li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">Page 2 <b class="caret"></b></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Page 2.0.0 </a></li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 2.0.1 </a></li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 2.0.2 </a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

CSS:

```
.dropdown-menu li:hover{
    background-color: green;
}
```

The class `dropdown-menu` should be hit and then when you hover over the `li`'s inside it. I have tried adding an id as dropdown menu and changing the CSS to `#dropdown-menu` but it made no difference.
Also, is there an easy way to find out exactly how to hit the appropriate element as I find this is a frequent problem?

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle?

Comment: Are you sure you mean color? I think the fact that they are links will override the color attribute https://jsfiddle.net/5mbtxn71/1/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/bf1cyptm/

Comment: @Donutttt changed to background, no difference

Comment: It seems as the answers have now solved the problem - I think the selector was part of what was causing the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok here we go,

here is the working solution of your problem,

```
.dropdown-menu > li > a:focus,
.dropdown-menu > li > a:hover {
    clear: both;
   background-color: green !important;
   background-image:none !important; 
    display: block;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1.42857;
    padding: 3px 20px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    color: black !important;
}
```

i have just edited your code
          http://jsfiddle.net/bf1cyptm/1/

:)

Comment: jsfiddle.net/bf1cyptm can you get it to work in here

Comment: this is good and will mark it correct. however, `.dropdown-menu > li > a:hover {
  
   background-color: #f0f !important;
   background-image:none !important; 
    color: black !important;
}` i think this is a slightly better solution as the dropdown elements don't jump around at all when hovering over them and they did when the padding element was present. nonetheless, cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `!important` in CSS like:

```
.dropdown-menu li a:hover{
    background-color:green !important;
}
```

If it does not work it could possibly be some other CSS code that is not letting it happen. So the solution to it is to do an inspect element and see which element is affecting it.
If you are not expert in than a best solution for you.
Please add a new class just after `dropdown-menu` like:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu colorchange">
```

and call CSS by it like:

```
.colorchange li a:hover{

    background-color: green;

}
```

It should work! You can use `important` here as well.

Answer (score -2):

Try this

```
 .dropdown-menu li:hover .dropdown-menu li a{
        color: green;
    }
```

Comment: If you intended to have two different selectors, you need to separate them with a comma (`,`).